# preg_match to retrieve value

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm using preg_match with PHP 5.6 to retrieve a value from a string.
**(I'm newb with preg_match)**

It goes with this format:

> data[SearchForm][somestringhere]

And I need to be able to retrieve the 'somestringhere' value.

I tried doing it this way:

```
$search_field_pattern   = "/\bdata[SearchForm][[a-zA-Z]]\b/i";
if(preg_match($search_field_pattern, "foo")) {
    debug('foobar!');
}
```

But it's not working.
Can someone give me a hint why it's not working and what I should do to correctly approach this solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$search_field_pattern  = "/\bdata\[SearchForm]\[(\w+)]/i";
if(preg_match($search_field_pattern, "data[SearchForm][somestringhere]", $m)) {
    echo $m[1]; // => somestringhere
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/E4KTtE)

The pattern matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `data\[SearchForm]\[` - a literal string `data[SearchForm][` (note `[` are escaped to match literal `[` chars)
- `(\w+)` - capturing group 1: one or more word chars
- `]` - a `]` char.

The third argument to `preg_match`, `$m`, will hold the results. Since the necessary substring is captured into Group 1, the value is retrieved using `$m[1]`.

---

To get the last substring inside square brackets you may use

```
if(preg_match("~\[(\w+)](?!.*\[\w+])~s", "data[SearchForm][somestringhere]", $m)) {
    echo $m[1]; // => somestringhere
}
```

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/Vus7N2).

To get the second one, use

```
if(preg_match("~\[\w+].*?\[(\w+)]~s", "data[SearchForm][somestringhere]", $m)) {
    echo $m[1]; // => somestringhere
}
```

See [yet another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/pCirJ0).

Comment: I was trying to not approach that due to ($search_field_pattern, "data[SearchForm][somestringhere]" that .. because I wanted to check atomically the value .. otherwise I could just go with strrpos

Comment: @Firecat Then what is the rule? Get all inside last `[...]`? The answer is matching your current question, please edit it if you meant something else.

Comment: @Firecat The *second* one in the string, or the *last* one in the string  (see [this demo](https://ideone.com/Vus7N2))?

Comment: The last one or the second one .. it doesn't matter because it will always be second parameters a

Comment: @Firecat I added all variations to the answer.